How can I place a typedef inside a class using macros?
I have a component registry that registers components (classes/types). I've succeeded in making it so that the system doesn't work if you try using it with a class that wasn't registered. However even if it was registered once with one type of registry then it works with all of them because there's a:
template <typename T> static inline component_id;

That is placed inside the class by the macro.
template <typename name>
struct ComponentRegistry
{
    using this_type = ComponentRegistry;

    template <typename component_t>
    static char register_new_component(const char* name)
    {
        static int counter = 0;
        component_t::template component_id<this_type> = counter++;
        /* REGISTER THE COMPONENT HERE*/
        
        return char(); /* ANYTHING. THE ONLY ONLY REASON THE DUMMY EXISTS IS TO TRIGGER THIS FUNCTION CALL ON PROGRAM INITIALIZATION */
    }
    template <typename component_t>
    int getComponentID()
    {
        /* IF THE COMPONENT WASN'T REGISTERED WITH ANY REGISTRY AT ALL, THEN THE template component_id DOESN'T EXIST AND SO IT WORKS
        - THE PROBLEM IS THAT EVEN IF IT WAS REGISTERED WITH ANOTHER REGISTRY THIS WILL STILL INSTANTIATE THE TEMPLATE
        - HOW DO I THROW A COMPILE ERROR? */
        return component_t::template component_id<this_type>; 
    }
};



#define REGISTER_COMPONENT_WITH_REGISTRY(comp_name, ecs_registry_type, comp_type) \
static inline char dummy_assignee_##ecs_registry_type = ecs_registry_type::register_new_component<comp_type>(comp_name); \
template <typename T> \
static inline int component_id;



struct ComponentRegistryName {}; // JUST USED TO DISTINGUISH. EACH TYPE CAN HAVE ITS OWN SET OF COMPONENTS

using ComponentRegistryType = ComponentRegistry<ComponentRegistryName>;

struct MyComponentType
{
    REGISTER_COMPONENT_WITH_REGISTRY("MyComponentTypeName", ComponentRegistryType, MyComponentType)

};

struct MyComponentType2
{
    /* NOT REGISTERED */
};

int main()
{
    ComponentRegistryType component_registry;

    component_registry.getComponentID<MyComponentType>(); // THIS SUCCEEDS BECAUSE IT WAS REGISTERED
    //component_registry.getComponentID<MyComponentType2>(); // THIS FAILS TO COMPILE BECAUSE THE COMPONENT WASN'T REGISTERED

}

This works well to check if the component was registered at all because if it wasn't:
But the problem is if I want to register the component to another registry type there's no restriction check anymore because when I do:
component_t::template component_id
Doesn't exist at all. However even if the getComponentID is called on with a template  argument of a component that was registered to ANY registry it succeeds. I was hoping to put a typedef in the class using the macro that I can check as a member, and if it exists, then it's good.

It seems to me that this is something that is typically solved using inheritance.

Something along these lines, perhaps:
// Declared but not defined.
template <typename Reg, typename Comp>
struct ComponentIdHolder;

The registration macro would then stamp out something like this:
template<>
struct ComponentIdHolder<ecs_registry_type, comp_type> {
  static inline int component_id;
};

The macro would be placed outside the component class, not inside as you have now.
Within the registry, you can access the component ID as ComponentIdHolder<this_type, component_t>::component_id. This would fail to compile for any pair of types for which the specialization wasn't provided.

That's really ingenious, thank you.

Oh, it goes outside. Templates can't be specialised inside classes?

No, that wouldn't compile

Woohoo, I got it working. I used your method, except I placed the original base template declaration inside the class too, so now nothing needs to be outside. Since it's inside I removed the component_type template parameter because it's not needed: https://godbolt.org/z/85fnMWEzM

@Zebrafish seems only clang and latest msvc  accepts that. gcc\mingw and older msvcs (not on goldbolt) reject don't all this tardis-specialization.  And I think they are right , specializationin C++17 requires to be in anmespace scope.

@Swift You're right, it doesn't compile in GCC. I'm going to go with Igor's answer, and place the register_component macro outside the class, after it's definition. It works pretty well, I'm happy with it. If it were compile-time ID assigning it would be better, but we can't have everything.

@Swift-FridayPie Also, you saved me about 4 hours of my life. I couldn't imagine trying to compile in GCC and trying to figure out why it wasn't working.
